# Wondering what the process for reopening a closed question here is?

Tags: support

[Version lie shim for SQL Server 2014](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66075/version-lie-shim-for-sql-server-2014)

The above question was closed (for incorrect reasons IMHO). I've answered the charges and the question hasn't been revisited. Is there no process whereby those who close questions periodically review those questions when they're edited to clarify any reasons that they may have been closed in the first instance for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a process, but it isn't a notification directly to the people who voted on the question. When a question has been closed and it is later edited, it enters the re-open queue. This happened to yours and community members voted to keep it closed:

> [image]

In any case, your question is probably more appropriate to be put directly toward the vendor. If a tool is checking `@@VERSION` there's no way to fool SQL Server into giving an inaccurate answer. However the vendor may have other workarounds, may be able to tell you when an update it coming, or may have a beta program to invite you to. We won't necessarily have that information.

Comment: _"If a tool is checking @@VERSION there's no way to fool SQL Server into giving an inaccurate answer"_. That's really the answer I was looking for in the original question. It was closed as being vendor specific, when I didn't think it was, but thanks for taking the time to come back to me on this...